# What is "Eye pull out" effect?

Tags: wasteland-2

Early in the game you can get a special Sniper Gun: Red Ryder BB Gun

> it's a prise for a Leg Lamp brought to museum.

It does 1 damage and "Eye pull out" effect. Can't get what is it, doesn't seem to affect enemy much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eye Put Out
Unique

Your mother warned you!

-30% Chance to Hit

10 seconds remaining

Can be removed with the appropriate item

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

This is a reference to the popular Christmas film, [A Christmas Story](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085334/).  In the movie the only gift the main character Ralphie wants is an authentic Red Rider BB Gun.

The most famous line from the movie, that is said by multiple characters, is "You'll shoot your eye out!"  This is the reference.

With the addition of the detail about it being a reward for finding a "leg lamp", I thought I'd add that that's yet another reference.  A lamp that resembles a leg is another plot point in the movie!

Comment: thus it does nothing useful? :)

Comment: I don't actually own the game, but according to [this Steam post](http://steamcommunity.com/app/240760/discussions/0/540734792723933977/) it blinds people.  This may be a joke, I'm not sure.